# Setting time using wheel in android

Tags: android

i am using the android wheel as time picker and getting the values as below

```
private void SetTime(Context activity, int hour, int minute) {                  
    LayoutInflater inf = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
    // layout of alert box contains
    View view = inf.inflate(R.layout.wheel, null);

    final WheelView hours = (WheelView) view.findViewById(R.id.hours);
    hours.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(activity, 0, 23,"%02d"));          
    hours.setCyclic(true);
    hours.setCurrentItem(expiryHour);
    Log.d(TAG, "for expiryHour123456 ---> " + expiryHour);

    final WheelView mins = (WheelView) view.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
    mins.setViewAdapter(new Mywheel(activity, 0, 59,"%02d"));
    mins.setCyclic(true);           
    mins.setCurrentItem(expiryMinute);
    Log.d(TAG, "for expiryMinute123456 ---> " + expiryMinute);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
    .setMessage("Set Time For Post To AutoDelete")
    .setView(view)              
    .setPositiveButton("Set",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            expiryHour = hours.getCurrentItem();
            Log.d(TAG, "for expiryHour ---> " + expiryHour);
            if(mins.getCurrentItem() > 0){
                expiryMinute = mins.getCurrentItem() + 4;
                Log.d(TAG, "for expiryMinute ---> " + expiryMinute);
            }else{
                expiryMinute = mins.getCurrentItem();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

when iam setting the time i am getting the correct values but ,once setting the time and again if i want to  change the time , the minute value is showing wrong. for example first i set it to 2:10 then i wanted to change now when i open its showing 2:14 which should not happen.Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the below lines from your code.

```
if(mins.getCurrentItem() > 0){
         expiryMinute = mins.getCurrentItem() + 4;
         Log.d(TAG, "for expiryMinute ---> " + expiryMinute);
}
```

This might the cause of the problem. Is there any specific reason of incrementing the mins value?

Comment: yes there is reason...after 00 i  display 05 ,skipping 01, 02,03,04

Comment: If that is the case, you can put condition like if(mins.getCurrentItem() == 0){
         expiryMinute = mins.getCurrentItem() + 4;
         Log.d(TAG, "for expiryMinute ---> " + expiryMinute);
}else{
         expiryMinute = mins.getCurrentItem();
}

Comment: my code is working..now iam getting issue when setting the value..the value iam getting correct but the number in wheel is changing

Answer (score 0):

Solved setting the value of minute wheel like this mins.setCurrentItem(expiryMinute-4);

```
final WheelView mins = (WheelView) view.findViewById(R.id.minutes);
            mins.setViewAdapter(new Mywheel(activity, 0, 59,"%02d"));
            mins.setCyclic(true);
            if(expiryMinute!=0){
            mins.setCurrentItem(expiryMinute-4);
            }
```